# Proof or counterexample to $ \int_a^t |f(x)|dx \leq \sup_t|\int f(x)dx| $

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, supremum-and-infimum, integral-inequality

I'm trying to finish off an exercise and the following identity would come in handy, if it were true

$$\int_0^t |f(x)|dx \leq \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} \left| \int_0^t f(x)dx \right|$$

Let's assume $f:[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is at least continuous. Does it hold? I was trying to imagine when it could fail, perhaps when there's lots of cancellation in the integral from large negative and large positive values of $f$, which would add up to become big in the $|f(x)|$ integral but would end up being zero for the $f(x)$ integral, but then this would be prevented by the supremum, so I have a hunch it should work.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to put in an absolute value outside the integral. Allow me to edit the question.

Comment: Then what about $f(x) = \sin x$? The right-hand side is bounded, while the left tends to infinity when $t$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Don't you still have to integrate $\sin(x)$ on the RHS from 0 to infinity so you still get a blowup, before you take any supremum?

Comment: You don't have to go out to infinity, just go out to 20 or something. The LHS will be large and the RHS is 1.

Comment: Hmm yes I see. What a shame I was hoping it was correct. Thanks for the answers everyone.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the actual exercise that you are trying to solve. The above estimate does apparently not hold in general, so you seem to be on a wrong track (i.e. this is an XY-problem).

Comment: @MartinR I was trying to find a uniform bound for a sequence of functions of the form $f_t^\varepsilon = \int_0^t \frac{|y_s|}{\varepsilon}ds$, where $y_s$ was some continuous function but I already had that $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|\int_0^t \frac{y_s}{\varepsilon}ds|$ is uniformly bounded. I'd have love to just gone $|f^\varepsilon_t| \leq |\int_0^t \frac{y_s}{\varepsilon}ds|$ but obviously its the reverse that holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing the integral with the absolute value inside should have an upper limit of $T$.  If so, then the inequality is reversed, and equality holds if and only if $f$ is either non-negative [almost everywhere] on $[0,T]$ or non-positive [almost everywhere] on $[0,T]$.

The reversed inequality is essentially the triangle inequality.

Comment: Do you mean with an infimum when you say the inequality holds in reverse?

Comment: No.  I mean it holds if you change $\leq$ to $\geq$ with no other change. (Again, assuming the left integral upper limit is $T$ instead of the current free $t$)

Comment: Surely then you could take any strictly positive $f$ such that $f = |f|$ and you would end up essentially saying $A \geq \sup A$?

Comment: And yes I am assuming you can't take $t$ more than $T$

Comment: If $f \geq 0$, it just says that the supremum occurs when $t=T$, which is true.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: If the integral on the left really is $\int_0^t$ for an arbitrary $t \in [0, T]$ rather than $\int_0^T$ then there's no inequality you can make between them.